# Updating jwt scope in token after it has been signed

Tags: java, spring-boot, oauth, jwt

A token is created with:

```
"oauth": {
    "client_id": "...",
    "redirect_uri": "...",
    "scope": "p1 p2 p3 p4 p5",
    "state": "...",
    "code_challenge": "...",
    "code_challenge_method": "..."
  }
```

This returns a signed jwt token with the scope options.

I want to update the signed jwt with a 'selected_person' int the claims, say p1, so i call the refresh token url passing in the refresh token and scope 'p1', do some logic on the backend and set the person id. This then adds the person id to a newly signed token, all is good:

```
eg. /token?client_id=x&grant_type=y&refresh_token=y&scope=p1
```

It's possible to call the same endpoint with any of the scopes first defined (p1, p2 etc) as Spring will compare the scope to the initial list of scopes and return a refresh token if it matches.

The problem arises when a new person gets linked to me, so now i would have p6. As each refresh token call is based on the first list, p6 does not exists and will not be allowed. If i logout and get a new token then p6 gets added to the scope.

Is there anyway i can add p6 to the scope without loggin out?

EDIT:

Ultimately is there a way to update originally granted scopes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lots of digging for answers and solutions, the requirement is simply not possible without logging out. As the documentation dictates

> scope (optional)
>
> The requested scope must not include additional
>   scopes that were not issued in the original access token. Typically
>   this will not be included in the request, and if omitted, the service
>   should issue an access token with the same scope as was previously
>   issued.

Ref: https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/access-tokens/refreshing-access-tokens/

Answer (score 0):

@dale You could try a slightly different method where you hold an internal mapping to the scope. But you would have to accept initials scopes as groups. However, what you are trying to achieve will not work for two reasons.

1. You are trying to change a signed document which will invalidate the document (JWT). but that doesn't really matter as it is for your use only.
2. If the subsequent API calls are linked to authorized scopes, the calls will not validate for you.

Comment: Yes i have gone down the route of an internal scope, thanks